# What is the query limit for @future method

Tags: apex, future

What is the query limit for @future method and can i use future method to fetch more than 50,000 records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limits are outlined in the [governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) documentation. Future methods are indeed limited to 50,000 rows. If you need to query more than this, you will need to use a [batchable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But there is a pliot program launched by Salesforce in which you can get 2x or 3x times the  normal limit. So can i use this to get higher limit.

Comment: @Mani Are you on the pilot program? If not, then you can't use it.

Comment: Please refer the below link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enhanced_future_overview.htm

Comment: @Mani If you're not on the pilot, you can not use it. You need to contact your customer success representative or your account executive to request access to this pilot.

Comment: Ok great.I m not aware of it. Thanks for your information